# ssh does not even access ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, authorized-keys

Here's the setup.

Up until 24 hours ago, the keys for password-less ssh logins worked fine. We used ever hour on the hour.

I then accidentally ran this command `ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub`

Ever since then, neither of my servers can access the sftp server without prompting for the password.

SELinux is permissive or disabled

Here are the permissions:

`[user@localserver .ssh]$ l
    total 32
    drwx------. 2 user user 4096 Jan 22 09:24 .
    drwx------. 4 user user 4096 Jan 22 09:24 ..
    -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  742 Jan 21 16:32 authorized_keys
    -rw-------. 1 user user  668 Jan 21 16:25 id_dsa
    -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  612 Jan 21 16:25 id_dsa.pub
    -rw-------. 1 user user 1675 Jan 21 16:39 id_rsa
    -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  404 Jan 21 16:39 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-rw-rw-. 1 user user  252 Jan 21 16:21 known_hosts`

When I turn on debug using -vvv, it doesn't even look at my authorized_keys file:

```
Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 384 bytes for a total of 1781
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 528 bytes for a total of 2309
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: The client doesn't read authorized_keys. When you try to connect to a remote system,the remote ssh server may read authorized_keys for the account you're trying to log into.

Comment: More to the point, your debug info just shows the client offered id_rsa and id_dsa, but the server didn't accept either one. You need to troubleshoot on the remote host to figure out why it's not accepting those keys.

Comment: @Kenster So this is something to do the remote ssh server? That seems to make the most sense since one minute I was working just find and then in one moment, no connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is due to my ignorance of ssh keys.

I sent them my pub keys. That is why the remote server failed to accept my rsa pub because I "ruined" my rsa key with what I did.

So I fresh generated my rsa keys, send over my pub keys, and viola, we are good to go.